# SQL Server (RDS instance) - Master user lost read permissions to a db

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have a SQL Server instance (AWS RDS). The master user lost access to one of the databases (able to access others). I might have accidentally given the master user denyreader or something similar. Tried resetting the master password on the AWS console, still no use.

Does anyone know how I can get the privileges back for the master user?

Thanks in advance
grav77

Comment: Was able to talk to AWS support after holding for nearly 4 hours (holiday schedule, I guess). They gave the sql to execute on the impacted db.

Comment: USE [database-name]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_denydatareader] DROP MEMBER [master-user-name]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_denydatawriter] DROP MEMBER [master-user-name]
GO